Magento2 unrelated image is loading for first 3 secs
While creating new product in the image section unwanted or non related image is loading for first 3secs.Before actual product image is loading how to resolve this?
The particular image is loading from cache i have cleared cache also.
I expected only newly created image should load

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
